# Cannot find the databaseAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dbname' in Magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento, localhost

I have migrated the Magento files from live server to localhost by following the [link](http://developerspark.net/2012/07/how-to-migrate-the-magento-from-localhost-to-live-server/). Made changes as per the link. When I load the file on my localhost the front end with templates and design are loaded properly but throwing an error like **Cannot find the databaseAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dbname'**. Any one help me what are the changes need to be done.

[image: The error message screenshot is here]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try deleting local.xml file after taking its backup. Flush cache and check. Of course you need to place local.xml after that

Comment: app/etc folder should not have other backup xml files

Comment: @Joshi-->app/etc folder have additional and template xml files other than config and local xml files. I flushed the cache but still no use.

Comment: Did the server use any other cache system which is defined in `local.xml` file?

Comment: @Joshi-->sorry I don't know whether it is using other cache system or not. Now I used to clear the cache by deleting the files from the folder projectname/var/cache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the database creditials in the app/etc/local.xml. In this file try to change following

```
<username></username>
<password></password>
<dbname></dbname>
```

to your local host phpmyadmin creditials.

Comment: @pradeep-->Yes I modified the things as per my configurations, which is given in the link.